# How to include the marqee animation to slick slider or to make the original marqee draggable?

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I need the marqee as one of menus on my shop page.

At first I did it by css, it looked like that
[codepen](https://codepen.io/alexiusgrey/pen/jOXaXbZ?editors=1111)
But the client wants it being draggable, so I used slick slider.
I wanted to show on the codepen exactly with slick, but

```
 at t (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js:2:27330)" undefined
```

so I pasted the code that I use in slick, but on the codepen slick doesn't work, it works [on the website](https://muvre.com/shop/)

We both don't like slick animation, the first one was better, but it wasn't draggable and my client had problems to stop the animation on touch on mobile device.

So I need some mix of that two things. I tried to paste marquee 45s linear infinite to cssEase in slider settings,tried not to comment the animation, but it's chaos then - the css animation is dominating under slick. I tried to unset animation on hover in css, where is the animation-play-state: paused; I did animation: unset; it was a bad idea too - on hover it's not pausing where it was, it returns to its previous state. What's the way to make them work together?